# Create IdentityUserRole in a request

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to create the IdentityRole in a request, but I can't apply it to the database. Here's the code:

```
if (registerUser.Admin)
{
  var role = await _roleManager.FindByIdAsync("Administrador");
  if(role != null)
  {
    var userRole = new IdentityUserRole<string>
    {
      UserId = user.Id,
      RoleId = role.Id
    };
  }
}
else
{
  var role = await _roleManager.FindByIdAsync("25F3226654FD457E99C35B9A62B9CE3C");
  if (role != null)
  {
    var userRole = new IdentityUserRole<string>
    {
      UserId = user.Id,
      RoleId = role.Id
    };
  }
}
```

OBS: It's worth mentioning, when I look for these Roles I can't find them by name, but by id with you.

I will attach how I create this Role:

```
builder.Entity<IdentityRole>().HasData(new IdentityRole { Id="6596B380EC604E9A8708924CCCD717EC", Name= "Administrador" });
builder.Entity<IdentityRole>().HasData(new IdentityRole { Id = "25F3226654FD457E99C35B9A62B9CE3C", Name = "DefaultUser" });
```

Along with the code above, I created a "standard" user, and I can pass the Role to him, here's the code:

```
builder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<string>>().HasData(new IdentityUserRole<string> { UserId = "0CD0E173758F4492B41EDD4A51D36BA5", RoleId = "6596B380EC604E9A8708924CCCD717EC" });
```

So it means that I am not able to do such a process in the request only, any idea how I can do this?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `== null` instead of `!= null`?

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#next-steps

Comment: Using SQLProfiler check if there is calls to database server.

Comment: And, Using SQLProfiler select following interesting events: ErrorLog, User Error Message, Exception, ErrorLog.

Comment: Role is the Role that is in the database it must not be null because I will make a reference to it in another table.